# Firebase data modeling guidance

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

At the risk of being tagged duplicate, here goes.

I have items and tags. Items can have many tags, and each tag can be a child tag of another tag.

I want to list tags as a tree, and items inside each tag.

In essence, a tag is a folder for items, except an item can be in multiple locations.

Is this the right way?

```
/items/

i123 : {
     Label : "i am an item",
     Tags  : { tagid: t234}
}

/tags/

t234 : {
     Label : "i am a Tag",
     Parent: {tagid: t567}
}
```

Im a bit unsure that I'm doing this right. I did read through the demoralizing document and tutorial at firebase of course and I did look at other similar questions.

I'm stuck in RDBMS-think and seem unable to grok the nosql concepts, that's why I hope to get some guidance here for the use case here.

Thanks.

**Per request from commenters, more info on the use case.**

I'm trying to display a tree of tags, like this

```
I am tag One
I am second tag
    this is a child tag
         here is a child's child tag
    another child tag
I am a root level tag again
// etc... you get the idea
```

There are also items, and items can be in multiple tags. The display here is exactly as in a file browser, really. Except here, items can be located in multiple places, i.e. they can have multiple tags associated.

Like this example, where `item 334` sits in multiple places:

```
tag 1
item 209
tag 2
    tag 21
    item 11
    item 334
tag 3
item 334
item 586
```

Right now, I think I could just store the whole thing in one JSON object, and update as needed, but I'm interested in being searchable by tag as well as item label. So in my feeble newbie mind, I assume I should be able to have a URL `/tags/` that I can traverse to get items matching the tags. Ditto for `/items/` so I can do a keyword match on the labels.

Other answers on SO describe ways to create indices for things, that's why I'm storing tag references in my item object. I'm struggling with the details around this.

The more I think about it, the more inclined I am to simply store everything in one big nested object, but I think that's supposed to be not a good idea. And I particularly dislike the idea of having an item stored multiple times if I did that.

Life was easier in RDB world, because I knew what I was doing :P

Comment: The right way to model your data, depends on how your app needs to consume that data. We cannot answer that for you, although we can help with a specific query if you have that. Aside from that, I recommend reading this article on [NoSQL Data Modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I thought I was pretty clear in my description on how it's going to consume data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This structure meets the criteria of your question but there's really not information in the question to put a solid answer together.

```
items
 item_00
   tag_00
   tag_01
   tag_02
 item_01
   tag_02
 item_02
   tag_01

tags
 tag_00
   parent: false
   child: tag_01
 tag_01
   parent: tag_00
   child: false
 tag_02
   parent: false
   child: false
```

In this example,

- items can have many tags
- each tag can be a child of another tag (and the parent:child relationship is tracked)
- the tags are listed as a tree
- items inside each tag can be found by querying the items for the tag
  number

Update the question with more data and I (we) can refine the answer)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this. I'll have to think about how best to ask. Don't want to pollute the question with unnecessary detail.